# How do I properly use deleteMany() with an $and query in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I am trying to delete all documents in my collection `infrastructure` that have a `type.primary` property of "pipelines" and a `type.secondary` property of "oil."

I'm trying to use the following query:
`db.infrastructure.deleteMany({$and: [{"properties.type.primary": "pipelines"}, {"properties.type.secondary": "oil"}] })`,

That returns: `{ acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0 }`

I expect my query to work because in MongoDB Compass, I can retrieve 182 documents that match the query `{$and: [{"properties.type.primary": "pipelines"}, {"properties.type.secondary": "oil"}] }`

My documents appear with the following structure (relevant section only):

```
properties": {
                "optional": {
                    "description": ""
                },
                "original": {
                    "Opername": "ENBRIDGE",
                    "Pipename": "Lakehead",
                    "Shape_Leng": 604328.294581,
                    "Source": "EIA"
                },
                "required": {
                    "unit": null,
                    "viz_dim": null,
                    "years": []
                },
                "type": {
                    "primary": "pipelines",
                    "secondary": "oil"
                }
...
```

My understanding is that I just need to pass a filter to `deleteMany()` and that `$and` expects an array of objects. For some reason the two combined isn't working here.

Comment: where you are executing this delete query?

Comment: @turivishal in the MongoDB Compass mongo shell

Comment: did you executed command `use <database name>` before executing query?

Comment: @turivishal yes

Comment: Your query filter works fine in `mongo` shell with the `find` and the `deleteMany` methods. You get the result like this `{ acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0 }` when there are no matching documents (probably, they were deleted in your earlier try).

Comment: @turivishal upon further review I realize I spelled my database name incorrectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the simplest answer was the correct one -- I spelled my database name incorrectly.